# Regular Expression when containing quotes in python

Tags: python, regex

I have the following line that I scrape *directly* off an html page. I want to process it to extract information from it:

```
var quoteDataObj = [{"symbol":".DJIA","symbolType":"symbol","code":0,"name":"Dow Jones Industrial Average","shortName":"DJIA","last":"15794.08","exchange":"Dow Jones Global Indexes","source":"Exchange","open":"15630.64","high":"15798.51","low":"15625.53","change":"165.55","currencyCode":"USD","timeZone":"EST","provider":"CNBC Quote Cache","altSymbol":".DJIA","curmktstatus":"REG_MKT","realTime":"true","assetType":"INDEX","noStreaming":"true","encodedSymbol":".DJIA"}]
```

I am using python to process the string above which I've saved into the variable "line". . I'm trying to write a regular expression that gets

```
"low":"15625.53"
```

However, I don't know what the number will be so I can't just search that. I've tried the following but with no luck:

```
last = re.search(r".*last\":.*\,", line)
```

Thanks!

Comment: What is `line`? What's this `var` keyword supposed to do? Are you sure you're using Python?

Comment: strip off that javascript, throw the rest in `json.loads`.

Comment: Please see my revised edits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`r'"low":".*?"'` should work for you.

```
>>> re.search(r'"low":".*?"', text).group()
'"low":"15625.53"'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
cruft,sep,payload = s.partition(' = ')

from ast import literal_eval # or 100% equivalent for this purpose, json.loads

d_in_list = literal_eval(payload)
```

Then you just have a regular `dict` in a `list`.

```
d_in_list[0]
Out[15]: 
{'altSymbol': '.DJIA',
 'assetType': 'INDEX',
 'change': '165.55',
 'code': 0,
 'curmktstatus': 'REG_MKT',
 'currencyCode': 'USD',
 'encodedSymbol': '.DJIA',
 'exchange': 'Dow Jones Global Indexes',
 'high': '15798.51',
 'last': '15794.08',
 'low': '15625.53',
 'name': 'Dow Jones Industrial Average',
 'noStreaming': 'true',
 'open': '15630.64',
 'provider': 'CNBC Quote Cache',
 'realTime': 'true',
 'shortName': 'DJIA',
 'source': 'Exchange',
 'symbol': '.DJIA',
 'symbolType': 'symbol',
 'timeZone': 'EST'}

d_in_list[0]['low']
Out[16]: '15625.53'
```

Though really there is a 99% chance that there exists an actual API where you can submit a query and get the above `json` response back without having to scrape a webpage and do janky parsing.

Comment: This works great as well, unfortunately, i couldn't find an API but for something this small, it works either way. Thanks for pointing me in this direction too!

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to strip the `var ...` prefix and deal with the string as a JSON object:

```
>>> import json
>>> data = 'var quoteDataObj = [{"symbol":".DJIA","symbolType":"symbol","code":0,"name":"Dow Jones Industrial Average","shortName":"DJIA","last":"15794.08","exchange":"Dow Jones Global Indexes","source":"Exchange","open":"15630.64","high":"15798.51","low":"15625.53","change":"165.55","currencyCode":"USD","timeZone":"EST","provider":"CNBC Quote Cache","altSymbol":".DJIA","curmktstatus":"REG_MKT","realTime":"true","assetType":"INDEX","noStreaming":"true","encodedSymbol":".DJIA"}]'
>>> json.loads(data[data.find('['):])
[{u'altSymbol': u'.DJIA', u'code': 0, u'last': u'15794.08', u'name': u'Dow Jones Industrial Average', u'noStreaming': u'true', u'exchange': u'Dow Jones Global Indexes', u'assetType': u'INDEX', u'symbol': u'.DJIA', u'realTime': u'true', u'symbolType': u'symbol', u'high': u'15798.51', u'source': u'Exchange', u'encodedSymbol': u'.DJIA', u'low': u'15625.53', u'provider': u'CNBC Quote Cache', u'curmktstatus': u'REG_MKT', u'timeZone': u'EST', u'shortName': u'DJIA', u'open': u'15630.64', u'currencyCode': u'USD', u'change': u'165.55'}]
>>> json_str = data[data.find('['):]  # Take everything from the first [ in the string
>>> json.loads(json_str)[0]['low']
u'15625.53'
```

You can retrieve every attributes from your array then.